# Dark mode changer

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="color-wrapper">
    Hello world
  </div>

  <input id="dark-mode" type="checkbox">
  <label for="dark-mode">Dark mode</label>
</body>
<style>
:root {
  --bg: pink;
}

#dark-mode:checked ~ #color-wrapper {
  --bg: orange;
}

#color-wrapper {
  background: var(--bg);
}
</style>
</html>
```

It has to change background color of the "Hello world" text then I check the checkbox, but it does not, the color is always pink. What is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tilde selector `~` selects siblings after the element, so change order of elements in your html to fix:

```css
:root {
  --bg: pink;
}

#dark-mode:checked ~ #color-wrapper {
  --bg: orange;
}

#color-wrapper {
  background: var(--bg);
}
```

```html
  <input id="dark-mode" type="checkbox">
  <label for="dark-mode">Dark mode</label>
    <div id="color-wrapper">
    Hello world
  </div>
```